# startup script remain running in background

Tags: bash, scripting, startup

I use severals window managers as icewm openbox wmaker and others
For these i have one generic startup

In one line i have (to load in traybar one volume control applet according wich is installed in the system in one moment):

```
(pnmixer || volumeicon || volti || pa-applet || pasystray || padevchooser) 2>/dev/null &
```

When i use this line, i note what the startup script remain running in background (is listed if i run xfce4-taskmanager or with ps command)

Because it, i opted to rewrite this line so:

```
if [ -f /usr/bin/pnmixer ]; then pnmixer &

elif...

elif...

fi
```

The problem? can be noted too (the prompt do not return) if in a terminal i write:

```
(anyword || ls) &
```

Why the prompt do not return? or the startup remain running? Is possible to use the first line proposed without to use  if then ?

Comment: Is the prompt redrawn if you press `Enter` once? Is the background job listed if you use the `jobs` command in the terminal afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

I can not reproduce your problem. Just try hitting `Enter` as Kusulananda suggested.

Do you have substantially different output in the following?

```
$ (anyword  || ls -a )& echo main is back; sleep 2; echo finished
[3] 450612
main is back
anyword: command not found
.  ..
[3]-  Done                    ( anyword || ls --color=auto -a )
finished
$
```

Comment: Yes. The prompt redrawn if i press Enter once. - My intention is that it was not necessary to press enter - With this last example, running (anyword  || ls -a )& sleep 1 <ENTER>  the problem is solved, although I do not understand why the sleep is necessary - Thanks for the answers

Comment: @cefer, that's just how running background processes in bash works.  bash doesn't display the `[n]+ Done ...` message until the next prompt **after** the background job has finished (obviously, it can't display it before then because it hasn't finished yet).   The `sleep` command delays the prompt after starting the background job long enough for the job to finish before the next prompt - if the job took more than the sleep time, then it wouldn't and you'd be back to having to press enter to get a new prompt.

Comment: @cefer, obviously your prompt appeared and you could type command. Only the content of the terminal was mingled by your background job. `Enter` key served just to execute the first empty command and show you yet another prompt. `Ctrl-L` is an alternative: it tells your shell to redraw the terminal window -- this way you can see the first prompt and the (empty) command you (maybe) type again.